# POST process And look For result Data

Tags: c#, redirect

I'm using C# in send POST data to some page ! It's Really Work ...
I want Ask how i can work with Result data (GET)...
I want know if Results have redirect to Another page ....

```
string Uname = username.Text;
string Pass = (item.Text);
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string pastData = POST1.Text + "=" + Uname + "&" + POST2.Text + "=" + Pass + "&" + Subtxt.Text;
// MessageBox.Show(pastData);
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(pastData);
WebRequest requst = WebRequest.Create(url.Text);
requst.Method = "POST";
requst.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
requst.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream stream = requst.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();
WebResponse response = requst.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

This Code is work to Send POST Without problem

I Want know if sr value have redirect to another page ...

I have some Idea .. i'm Search For redirect word in `sr` .. 
Some website not found redirect word on back Data(GET) .. but it redirect ...

**Conclusion : **

if i have admin page website ... I'm send POST with true Data .. i Want know if it Result redirect to page admin Manager

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to set `AllowAutoRedirect` to false on the request (you will need to cast it to `HttpWebRequest`). Then you can inspect the response code and see if it is a redirect. The redirected target page should be in the Location header.

```
private static void NoRedirect(string uri)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", resp.Headers["Location"]);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: On Browser Normal : 
Redirect not work in page admin ... redirect work in click submit and check user name and password is true 
But in 
C# coder in up Code 
Not Redirect in admin page Redirect before check username and password , 
Redirect after Check username and password POST process ..